# NAND technology - ecc error

Tags: microchip, non-volatile-memory, nand, nand-flash

Nand technology has some issues, which I find it a bit difficult to understand.
It is said in nand devices that manufacture guaranty that a page will have no more than X (4/8/16,etc according to nand device) failed bit.

1. Is it that the manufacture can really guarantee that there shall never be more than this amount of failed bits is a single page ?
2. Is it that the failed ecc happens just randomly, after some time ?
3. Is it that re-program the failed ecc page, shall recover its flip bits to the correct value ?

Thank you,
Ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, it's all a game of probabilities. You just define a probability (e.g. \$1-10^{-14}\$) that all pages fulfill that criterion, the manufacturer models the stochastic process that leads to errors and makes observations of that process, and you so get to a probability that indeed your criterion is fulfilled.
2. There's different kind of errors. But yes, spontaneous bit flips can happen for thermal, particle / ionizing radiation, or current leakage reasons. Other errors are not spontaneous, but always immediately manifest. Note that a flipped bit doesn't mean the ECC *must* fail: Error checks are only safe against certain patterns of bit errors, and if multiple bits within a block (or page, or whatever you call it) fail, the ECC might not "notice" it. It's, again, a stochastic thing.
3. Only if

   1. some recovery mechanism recovered the original data *correctly*; again, patterns, probability, and
   2. the reason the page failed because a bit flipped randomly. Of course, if a bit cell is simply stuck to a value, then there's nothing rewriting could solve.

Comment: I don't see the probability value in datasheet, so for example for a device such as MT29F4G08ABBDAH4, which is 4-biit ecc, the probability should be really low as you've described  (e.g. 10^-14)  ?

Comment: and another question, does oob (the additional info per page) is guaranteed to be correct ? Thanks!

Comment: you'll have to take a bitter pill: there's no certainty outside of math. Every device, every aspect of every device, just has an error probability. In good cases, this probability is close to 0.

Comment: That I understand, I just don't see why they don't write the probablity in datasheet. Myabe they mean that 5% there won't be error above 4-bit per page ? 5% is much more than 10^-14

Comment: The y will say whatever they can, in the end, financially afford to disappoint a customer. When you buy memory modules for places where "nearly all work" isn't good enough, you call them, and get more expensive chips with a specific probability.

Comment: Is there a nand without error probability ? it's for a safety product

Comment: no, didn't you read what I said? There's nothing *in this universe* that happens with 100% certainty. A lot of things are *highly likely* (like your chair not exploding spontaneously), but you cannot make guarantees. You can only increase or decrease probabilities. A specific probability will have to do. Quantum physics doesn't care whether you're the military, someone designing a life-critical medical device or the pope...

Comment: Marcus, you mentioned that a bit cell can be stuck on a value, so that rewriting won't solve it. in such case shouldn't it be declared as bad block ? (though bad block is defined as error in writing according to my docs) I think that ecc errors should always be fixed with rewriting. Thx